# Why does performSelector: crash my application?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have this method in my app:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(resetAdView:toView:) withObject:currentDelegate_ afterDelay:10];
```

It call another method and send an object to the method too....

I call this method every time i open a new `UIViewcontroller` to add an Ad to the view.
After i create a new `UIViewController`->call this method(the `currentdelegate` is the new `UIViewController`) and press back in the view controller and then i get after 10 seconds this error:

```
Thread 1 : EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1,address=0xd0000008)
```

Any idea what is wrong ? why i get this error?

Comment: Are you sure that 'self' is implementing the resetAdView:toView method ?

Comment: Yes this crash occur only when i create new UIViewController and then press back to go back to the previous viewcontroller

Comment: The selector you specify can only have zero or one arguments. You can't call a selector with two arguments using the `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` method.

Comment: @maddy, you should make that an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because your view controller gets released when you press back. 
If you are using ARC then make it a ivar so that it is doesn't get released.
And if you are using Non ARC env then please retain that view controller objet.

Answer (score 0):

you haven't given us enough info to help you, so I will give you generic advice:
add an exception breakpoint, if that doesn't give you enough info, the. turn on zombies, if that isn't enough, turn on malloc logging... if that isn't enough then you will need to learn more about your development environment.

Comment: I get this msg : message sent to deallocated instance 0x2217eb90 . but i dont understant it because i call a method and send a deallocated instance. This is wrong? i can't check in the method i call to check it?

Comment: turn on zombies, they you can know what class is the deallocated instance,  then you can trace it backwards to find out if it is over released or under retained...

Comment: or just while you are at the breakpoint in the debugger you may be able to find the variable ( or property) that matches that address.